# Media query with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a web page. There is a navigation section on the left that is all nested in `<p>` something like this.

```
    <nav>
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>About</p>
        <p>Shop</p>
        <p>Contact Us</p>
    </nav>
```

I have used `flexbox` to make this appear on the `left-hand` side of the page and be rendered `vertically`.

However, when I make the screen size smaller this has to be rendered horizontally (in one line with fixed spaces) at the top like a header.

This is what I have done so far:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;}}
```

**This appears all in one line with no spaces at all**.

When I add `justify-content: space-between`, it will add the spaces but as the `screen size decreases` it will all end up squashed. Therefore there is no fixed distance.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Im using codepen

Comment: i'm asking you if you are using bootstrap third library.

Comment: No im not using that

Comment: why not use a css-grid? that exactly what css-grid is for.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define padding for your p element

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    p {
       padding: 0 1rem;
     }
    }
```

Comment: my pleasure! can you please also accept my answer too. Please

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and set your `flex-direction` to `column`.

```
nav {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```